# Using get() on a dataframe

Tags: r, get, dataframe

I have a variable (x) containing a character string ("b"). This string gives the name of a variable which is contained in a dataframe (ABC). When trying to use the function get() to retrieve the value of the variable in the dataframe, I get an "object not found" error.

```
a <- 1
b <- 2
c <- 3
ABC <- data.frame(a,b,c)
x <- "b"
```

This works:

```
get(x)
  [1] 2
```

While this gives an error:

```
get(paste("ABC$",x,sep=""))
  Error in get(paste("ABC$", x, sep = "")) : object 'ABC$b' not foundhere
```

Although this works:

```
ABC$b
  [1] 2
```

How can I use the variable x to see the value of variable b?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are making things way too complex.

```
ABC[,x]
```

or

```
ABC[[x]]
```

should work fine.

Comment: Oooh, I was so stupid ... Thank you! But at least I have an excuse: For some reason, my variable x (which came from an external source using read.table) had the mode numeric. Of course, this causes the "object not found error", then. If I use ABC[[as.character(x)]], then everything is fine. Thanks, again!

Comment: Further, if you want to check if x stores a valid name of your data frame, the test is  " x %in% names(ABC) "

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
> get(x, ABC)
[1] 2
```

or

```
> ABC[[x]]
[1] 2
```